# How do you link one or more controllers to a view in MVC 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to display data from multiple tables into a single view that gives the user the ability to add, change, or delete data as needed.  So far I have not been able to even get one single view to work with a controller, much less multiple controllers with one view.  I am using MVC 5, VS 2013 (C#), and the database is hosted on another computer.

This is the Home Controller:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vivace.Models;

namespace Vivace.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public VivaceContext db = new VivaceContext();
        List<Distributor> list = new List<Distributor>();
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
         //   var ist = db.Distributors.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Address == "").Orders.ToList();
         //   var i = db.Distributors.Where(x => x.Address == "").ToList();
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            //ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";z

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            //ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Ordering()
        {
            //ViewBag.Message = "Place your orders."

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Inventory(string Categories)
        {
            //ViewBag.Message = "View items currently in stock.";
            var categoriesModel = new Category
            {
                CatName = Categories,
                Items = this.db.Items.ToList()
            };
            return this.View(categoriesModel);
        }

        public ActionResult Item()
        {
            return View();
        }


    }
}
```

This is the Item Controller (Item is the name of one of the tables I want to display data from):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Vivace.Models;

namespace Vivace.Controllers
{
    public class ItemController : Controller
    {
        private VivaceContext db = new VivaceContext();

        // GET: /Item/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var items = db.Items.Include(i => i.Category1).Include(i => i.Department1).Include(i => i.Distributor1);
            return View(items.ToList());
        }

        // GET: /Item/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Item item = db.Items.Find(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: /Item/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CatNumber", "CatName");
            ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DeptNum", "DeptName");
            ViewBag.Distributor = new SelectList(db.Distributors, "DistributorNumber", "DistributorName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: /Item/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include="ItemNumber,UPC,ItemName,Category,Department,Price,Cost,MarkUp,OnHand,InWherehouse,OnOrder,OnFeature,ShelfCap,Distributor")] Item item)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Items.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CatNumber", "CatName", item.Category);
            ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DeptNum", "DeptName", item.Department);
            ViewBag.Distributor = new SelectList(db.Distributors, "DistributorNumber", "DistributorName", item.Distributor);
            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: /Item/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Item item = db.Items.Find(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CatNumber", "CatName", item.Category);
            ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DeptNum", "DeptName", item.Department);
            ViewBag.Distributor = new SelectList(db.Distributors, "DistributorNumber", "DistributorName", item.Distributor);
            return View(item);
        }

        // POST: /Item/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include="ItemNumber,UPC,ItemName,Category,Department,Price,Cost,MarkUp,OnHand,InWherehouse,OnOrder,OnFeature,ShelfCap,Distributor")] Item item)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(item).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.Category = new SelectList(db.Categories, "CatNumber", "CatName", item.Category);
            ViewBag.Department = new SelectList(db.Departments, "DeptNum", "DeptName", item.Department);
            ViewBag.Distributor = new SelectList(db.Distributors, "DistributorNumber", "DistributorName", item.Distributor);
            return View(item);
        }

        // GET: /Item/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Item item = db.Items.Find(id);
            if (item == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(item);
        }

        // POST: /Item/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Item item = db.Items.Find(id);
            db.Items.Remove(item);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

This is the View that I want to display data on (the text boxes are there to allow for submitting new data, i.e. orders, or to search for previous orders):

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Ordering";<input id="Text1" type="text" />
}

<h2>Ordering</h2>

<fieldset>
    <legend>Order Information</legend>
    <form>
        <p><label for="distributor">Distributor:</label>
           <input type="text" name="distributor" value="@Request.Form["distributor"]" /></p>
        <p><label for="product">Product:</label>
           <input type="text" name="product" value="@Request.Form["product"]"/></p>
        <p><label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
           <input type="number" name="quantity"  value="@Request.Form["quantity"]"/></p>
        <p><label for="date">Date:</label>
           <input type="date" name="date" value="@Request.Form["date"]"/></p>
        <input type="submit" value="Place Order">
    </form>

    <legend>Order History</legend>
    <label>Search by:</label>
    <form>
        <p>
            <label for="distributorHist">Distributor:</label>
            <input type="text" name="distributorHist" value="@Request.Form["distributorHist"]" /></p>
        <p>
            <label for="productHist">Product:</label>
            <input type="text" name="productHist" value="@Request.Form["productHist"]" /></p>
        <p>
            <label for="dateHist">Date:</label>
            <input type="date" name="dateHist" value="@Request.Form["dateHist"]" /></p>
        <input type="submit" value="View History">
    </form>
</fieldset>
```

Is there something that I am missing?

Edit:
I think I learned how to implement a partial view, but now I am getting a new error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Compilation Error

Description: An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately. 

Compiler Error Message: CS0103: The name 'item' does not exist in the current context

Source Error:


Line 36: 
Line 37:     <td>
Line 38:         @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UPC)
Line 39:     </td>
Line 40:     <td>

Source File: c:\Users\Dragonfett\Documents\School\Spring 2014\CMPS 285\Group_6-CMPS_285\Vivace\Vivace\Views\Home\Ordering.cshtml    Line: 38 


Show Detailed Compiler Output:

Show Complete Compilation Source:


Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34009
```

I moved this snippet of code from the Item View called Index to the Ordering View:

```
<td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.UPC)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ItemName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Price)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Cost)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MarkUp)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OnHand)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InWherehouse)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OnOrder)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.OnFeature)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ShelfCap)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Category1.CatName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Department1.DeptName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Distributor1.DistributorName)
    </td>
    <td>
        @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.ItemNumber }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { id = item.ItemNumber }) |
        @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.ItemNumber })
    </td>
```

I am lost.

Answer (score 1):

Make the common view a Partial View.

Have a separate cshtml for each view for each controller, but merely have them load the partial view.

Comment: It automatically generates the view for each and every controller, I just showed the one I was working with as an example because of how many there are.

Now, how do I make the common view a Partial View?

Answer (score 0):

you can use ViewBag to store data of one table and pass it to View while passing other table data as a model to view. But the best approach is to Creat a ViewModel class for the view and then map that ViewModel class to the Model (domain) classes. Use automapper for mapping you ViewModel to Model class.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/687061/Using-Multiple-Models-in-a-View-in-ASP-NET-MVC-M